# Azure Portal : IPs of "selected network" disappear after some time

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azureportal

**Scenario :**

- Go to azure Portal
- Somehow, have a "Azure Cosmos Db Account" resource
- Open it and go to its "Networking" tab.
- In the right-side panel, go to the "Public access" tab
- Toggle "selected networks"
- A new pair of text boxes appears below to let you enter an IP
- **Enter an IP**
- **Click "Save"**

It takes an excruciatingly long time to save, but eventually the IP gets added.

> I know it worked because in my specific case I use that Azure Cosmos
> Db Account to let an Azure Data Factory workflow sink data into a
> Cosmos Db. Without that IP, I get error messages about a failed
> connection.

**Problem : After a certain amount of time (10, 20 minutes?), that IP disappears.** I have to do it all over again.

**Why?**

Answer (score 1):

If you trying to access the cosmos DB using Azure portal, enable the `Allow access from portal` option after selecting the particular range of IP's then the network IPs won't disappear.

[image]

*Other possible causes of this problem include:*

1. If the IP address you added to the Azure Cosmos DB account is dynamic, then it means, it can change over time. If the IP address changes, it will no longer be able to connect to the Cosmos DB account, and you will need to add the new IP address to the public access list.

   Instead of it, use a static IP address or a range of IP addresses that are permitted to access the Cosmos DB account.
2. There may be a firewall setting enabled for the provided Ip's in selected networks. If that is the case, the firewall will remove the specific IP if it is not in use over a period of time.
3. Verify whether any Azure policies have been added for the selected network's disallowed purpose. In that case, IP addresses from the selected networks may also disappear.

*After checking the above, I tried the same requirement in my environment, checked to see if it was enabled after some time, and it worked as follows:*

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Apparently in Azure you can create "robots" with rules such as "delete all foreign IPs periodically, for security reasons" -- similarly to what Firewalls do. This seems to have been one of the corporate policies of my company. Therefore, each time I was adding an IP, one of those bots would delete it after some time.

Comment: @Jahnavi 's answer is the same as mine, just explained in detail. I will mark his/hers as correct.